# Create bean with bean definition without registering

Tags: spring

As you already know, if I want to create bean in spring dynamically, I use this snipped code:

```
BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = ((BeanDefinitionRegistry )factory);
GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
beanDefinition.setBeanClass(MyBeanClass.class);
beanDefinition.setAutowireCandidate(true);
registry.registerBeanDefinition("dynamicBean",beanDefinition);
getApplicationContext().getBean("dynamicBean");
```

In this approach we must first define a bean definition, register and then get it. But, I want to create Bean without registration, so for this purpose I used `createBean` method (of `beanFactory`). But, the input argument of `createBean` is `Class<T>`.

I, however, need to create bean with bean definition, without registering it. I've also debugged my project and found that `creatBean` is called from `AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory`. This method calls another `createBean` and this method has `beanDefinition` argument, but unfortunately this method is protected and I cannot use it.

So, my question is, how can I create bean with bean definition, but without registering?

I've thought a lot about it and found that I can handle this in two approaches,

1. After get bean then remove it from with `registery.removeBeanDefinition`, or,
2. Create a wrapper for `AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory` and use it.

However, I'm looking for an approach which will perform faster.

Comment: Have you tried to configure spring using spring Configuration in XML, Annotation or JavaConfig style : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html

Comment: Yes, but I try create bean programmatically without use any of them.

Comment: Could you tell us what you are trying to accomplish apart from what you already asked? Are you trying to get all dependencies auto wired to the *bean* without registering it within the application context?

Comment: Maybe it's weird, but if you see the createBean method of (the protected one) AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory you can find what do I want, it create bean without regetering in application context.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these is for you:

```
ConfigurableListableBeanFactory listableBeanFactory = (ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) this.beanFactory;
listableBeanFactory.registerSingleton("foo", foo);
foo = (Foo) listableBeanFactory.initializeBean(foo, "foo");
```

?